# Modified LinkedList not updating in text file itself

Tags: c++, data-structures, singly-linked-list

**The Intro:**
I'm working on a Project @Student Course Registration System,
my project is based on singly linked list, with file handling.

**The Problem:**
I have managed to modify the nodes in LinkedList, made a separate function to update my text file. But the problem is the file is not getting updated. On the console, I do see the items updated.

I have to work around modifying the text file without making a temporary one and copying items to that, which I know how to.

P.S : I have made a function which always loads all the required Text Files into the program at startup.

**Structure:**

```
struct Student {
    string stdID;
    string stdName;
    string stdSemester;
    Student  *next;
};
```

**Main:**

```
int main() {
    Student *Head = NULL;
    Student *Tail = NULL;
    Course *Headd = NULL;
    Course *Taill = NULL;

    UpdateDirectory(Head, Tail, Headd, Taill);
    Display(Head, Tail);
    _getch();
    string Value;
    getline(cin, Value);
    ModifyStudent(Value, Head);
    UpdateFile(Head, Tail);
    //Display(Head, Tail);
    return 0;
}
```

**Modify Function:**

```
void ModifyStudent(string Value, Student *&Head) {
    // Initialize:
    Student *Curr = NULL;
    Student *Temp1 = NULL;
    Student *Temp2 = NULL;
    Student *Obj = new Student;

    if (isEmpty(Head)) {
        cout << "\t\t\t\t       Underflow....\n\n";
        _getch();
    }
    else {
        Curr = Head;
        Temp1 = Head;
        while (Curr->stdID != Value) {
            Temp1 = Curr;
            Curr = Curr->next;
            }

        if (Curr->stdID == Value) {
            cout << "\t\t\t\t       Student  Found!!\n\n";
            cout << Curr->stdID << endl; // 1324
            cout << Temp1->stdID << endl; // 3424

            // Modify:
            cout << "\t\t\t\t       Enter New Student ID  :  ";
            getline(cin, Obj->stdID);
            cout << "\t\t\t\t       Enter New Student Name  :  ";
            getline(cin, Obj->stdName);
            cout << "\t\t\t\t       Enter New Semester  :  ";
            getline(cin, Obj->stdSemester);

            Temp1->next = Obj;
            Obj->next = Curr->next;
            Curr->next = NULL;
            delete(Curr);

            /// Save:
            cout << "\t\t\t\t       Record Is Being Updated, Please Wait.......\n\n" << endl;
            _getch();
            }
        }
}
```

**Update File:**

```
void UpdateFile(Student *&Head, Student *&Tail) {
    Student *Temp = NULL;
    fstream SFile;
    SFile.open("StudentRecords.txt", ios::trunc);

    if (isEmpty(Head)) {
        cout << "\t\t\t\t       UnderFlow\n" << endl;
    }
    else {
        Temp = Head;
        while (Temp->next != NULL) {
            cout << Temp->stdID << '\t' << Temp->stdName << '\t' << Temp->stdSemester << '\n';
            SFile << Temp->stdID << '\t' << Temp->stdName << '\t' << Temp->stdSemester << '\n';
            Temp = Temp->next;
        }
        cout << Temp->stdID << '\t' << Temp->stdName << '\t' << Temp->stdSemester << '\n';
        SFile << Temp->stdID << '\t' << Temp->stdName << '\t' << Temp->stdSemester << '\n';
        _getch();;
    }
    _getch();;
}
```

I have even used ios::trunc, but no effect.
Thank You!

Comment: Try to use `SFile.close()` in the end of the function `UpdateFile` and see if this solve the problem.

Comment: No, Didn't solve the problem

Comment: Suggestion: Separate the linked list from the payload. This way you can test the correctness of the linked list without all the noise of `Student` behaviour.

Comment: Please [explain to your Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) why you test for `next` and not the current node for `NULL` in `while (Temp->next != NULL)`

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say what the problem is. You did not provide the full source code; therefore we cannot compile the code.

To write a file, use the following. The file will be **overwritten** (this seems to be what you are looking for):

```
ofstream os{ "test.txt" };
if( !os )
  return -1;
if( !list.write( os ) )
  return -2;
```

Regarding your code, this is a more c++ like approach to single linked lists:

- Define a **data class/structure**. You may want to use the data with other classes, not only with a linked list, therefore keep it separated from node:

  ```
  class student_t
  {
  public:
    string id;
    string name;
    string semester;
    // ...
  };
  ```
- Define operations. One of the operations you need is **write**:

  ```
    ostream& write( ostream& os )
    {
      return os
        << id << endl
        << name << endl
        << semester << endl;
    }
  ```
- Define a node. A node is made of **data** and a **pointer to next node**:

  ```
  class node_t
  {
    friend class list_t; // or replace it with public:

    student_t data;
    node_t* pnext;
    // ...
  };
  ```
- Add a **constructor** and a **write** method:

  ```
    node_t( const student_t& s, node_t* pnext ) : data{ s }, pnext{ pnext } {}

    ostream& write_data( ostream& os )
    {
      return data.write( os );
    }
  ```
- Define a list class. The only data a list class holds is the **list’s head**. The class will gather all list operations like `write_data`, `push_front`, `display_data`, etc.

  ```
  class list_t
  {
    node_t* phead{ nullptr };

  public:

    void push_front( const char* id, const char* name, const char* semester )
    {
      phead = new node_t( student_t{ id, name, semester }, phead );
    }

    ostream& write( ostream& os )
    {
      node_t* pn = phead;
      while( pn && pn->write_data( os ) )
        pn = pn->pnext;
      return os;
    }
    //...
  };
  ```

And this is how you use it:

```
    int main()
    {
      list_t list;
      list.push_front( "J1", "Jon", "first" );
      list.push_front( "S1", "Steve", "first" );

      {
        ofstream os{ "test.txt" };
        if( !os )
          return -1;
        if( !list.write( os ) )
          return -2;
      } // the file is automatically closed here

      list.push_front( "A1", "Ava", "second" );

      {
        ofstream os{ "test.txt" };
        if( !os )
          return -1;
        if( !list.write( os ) )
          return -2;
      }

      return 0;
    }
```